# Singleton property variable Release and Access

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, singleton

Here is my problem i have a singleton class which i calling it form various classes and i have an property in that singleton class to pass self from current class(will do which initiation singleton ) which i using self object to call a method in current class from singleton. Here am making this proxy object(singleton property) to nil in singleton every time when making call to singleton class.

So if i running the application in fast and agin and again(i.e calling that singleton very fast) application get crash in web view did finish loading method.

Any suggestion and idea on this.

here code for reference.

```
    +(Signout *)sharedInstance{
        @synchronized(self) {
            if (signOutInstance == nil) 
            {
                signOutInstance= [[self alloc] init]; 
            }
        }
        return signOutInstance;
    }

    -(void)signOut {

        [self signOutWebView];

    }

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)twebView {

    if (nil != self.instance) {
        if ([self.instance respondsToSelector:@selector(removeIndicator)]) {
            [self.instance removeLoadingIndicator];
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be it help.

```
if (nil != self.instance) {
        if ([self.instance respondsToSelector:@selector(removeIndicator)]) {
            [self.instance removeLoadingIndicator];
            self.instance = nil;
        }
    }
```

debug your code through print statements to find why it is crashing also have you tried to use zombies to find the reason for crash.

Comment: by the way thanks for the post. here my problem is that webViewdelegate will always behave like it will little slow so when am calling this singleton immediately this self.instance will be nil so web viewdelegate will contain instance variable as nil now so getting crash